# Show that if every subsequence of $x_n:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ has a convergent subsequence converging to $a$, then $x_n \rightarrow a$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Knowing that if every $i$-th co-ordinate converges to $a_i$, then $x_n \rightarrow a$, we **can** reduce the question into:

> Show that if every subsequence of $y_n$ has a convergent subsequence converging to $y$, then $y_n \rightarrow a$.

An idea was to use Cantor's nested interval theorem, but afterwards I realized that the sets must be compact. The idea was very convoluted (recursively defining a subsequence of $y_n$ on smaller and smaller index sets. Hoped that by Cantor's theorem it would give me a unique $n_0$, where $\forall n > n_0$, the sequence would be convergent).

Hints on what to use is very welcome here.

**Answer** (based on TheSilverDoe's hint):

Firstly, let us prove this statement given by TheSilverDoe:

> If $\exists a$ such that $\forall (y_{n_k}), \exists (y_{n_{k_l}}) \rightarrow a$, then $a$ is the only unique limit point and the $y_n$ converges.

**Proof**: Suppose $\exists a'$, then there exist a subsequence that converges to $a'$, but then ALL of the subsequences of this subsequence tends to $a'$, not $a$. The uniqueness of the limit point is enough to say that $y_n$ is convergent, because then limsup($x_n$) = liminf($x_n$).

In fact this statement is already the answer to the question in the title. We can argue this co-ordinate wise if we want to be more precise ofc.

Comment: I edited the title, I mistyped. The original question is in the title, the one in the blockquote is what I think the question is equivalent to.

Comment: "Consider $y_n=(−1)^n$, any subsequence would have a convergent subsequence that converges to $1$" : what about the subsequence $(y_{2n+1})$ ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh I see

Comment: @TheSilverDoe but still, it doesn't remove the possibility that there exist another limit point, only that each subsequence has a subsequence that tends to $a$, at least I think so..

Comment: If there exists $a$ such that every subsequence has a subsequence that tends to $a$, then there can be only one limit point ($a$), and the sequence converges.

Comment: I see. Bravo. Never thought about this.